# Testing makeStyles conditional rules with enzyme and jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, chai

This is a minimal example (which I just made to elaborate my question)

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        background: ({isRead}) => isRead ? '#EA1D250D' : 'white', // <= I want to test this
    }
});

function Notification(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return <div className={classes.root}/>
}
```

How can I test both branches in the `background` rule of `makeStyles`?

I have tried to access it with a wrapper:

```js
    it('Renders correctly for unread messages', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Notification isRead={true}/>);

        // Now here how can I expect `background` to be `#EA1D250D`?
        expect(wrapper.find('div').first().props().style).to.have.property('background', '#EA1D250D');
    });
```

In the above test, the `style` property is actually `undefined`, since the styles are added through the `className`

So is there any way I can access the styling rules of `makeStyles` for testing purposes?

Comment: I always just test by doing a contains on the className prop. (contains because with the style preprocessor I'm using, the className is prefixed with other stuff before the specified style name). I'm my setup at least it not possible to do anything else, because the preproccessor has already run by the time the test runs.